# From XCode 4.2 to 4.3, new ViewController class .m files are defined differently. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2, xcode4.3, coding-style

Like most, I recently downloaded the latest version of XCode (4.3.1).  I've noticed that as I'm creating new `UIViewController` objects, the associated `.m` files contain additional class definition code that I haven't ever seen before.

Specifically, if I create a new `UIViewController` named 'TestViewController', I get the following `.m` file output.

```
\\... removed comments...
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

\etc...

The newly added code since XCode 4.3 is the portion under the `#import` statement:

```
@interface TestViewController ()

@end
```

What is the purpose this code?  Can/should anything go within the parenthesis?  Should any code go within the `@interface` and `@end` statements?

In short, what was the point of adding this code to the template?  As an interesting side note, when I tried creating an `NSObject` from a template, the above mentioned snippet of code wasn't added.  It might appear with other types class templates but at the moment I've only encountered it with `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is an [Objective-C class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html). It's used to define "private" variables, properties, and methods.

The idea is that the .h file should only contain publicly accessible properties and methods. Very often, when writing a view controller, there are methods that you will want/need to write, but these methods shouldn't be publicly visible (i.e., these methods should only be used in your .m file). You declare these methods in the class extension to keep it out of the public .h interface.

Comment: You can also do other handy things like privately conform to a protocol without making that information public

Answer (score 2):

That's a class extension and there's a good article on their uses [here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/).

Answer (score 1):

That is just a `class extension` to "hide" the properties/methods declaration from the header file within the implementation file, for more info see the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html). You don't have to use it but you'll find it very convenient created automatically.